# Dropdown menu can not save to datasource

Tags: google-app-maker

I have two tables (`ClientName` and `PMLprojects`), that are related.

I create a form `PMLprojects` to input data (create), but in the `Client_Name` field, the options list goes to the `ClientName` table.

My problem is, I can see options on `ClientName` from `PMLprojects` form, but I cannot save it to Datasource.

```
Main Panel -> PMLprojects
Panel Form -> Inherited PMLprojects
Relation : PMLprojects (many) --- ClientName (one)
```

```
Dropdown option : @datasources.ClientName.items
Dropdown value : @datasource.item.Client_Name. (with dot, I can not set only @datasource.item.Client_Name)
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Is Client_Name on the value binding a reference to a field in PLMprojects or is it the name of the relation between the two models?

Comment: Client_Name is field name in ClientName table. sorry it's little bit confusing about it's name.

Comment: If your form is for PMLprojects then your value binding cannot be to the field of another table. Based on your setup the binding should be to datasource.item.YourClientTableRelation.

Comment: Hi. This problem solved. Strange things is datasource on form 'Invalid' and I can save to table. I still do not know why.